# Need to subtract until value reaches limit / predict when inventory runs out

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop

I am working on a query that has these two tables:
Table A:

```
Store       NumItems
1           500
2           1000
3           575
```

Table B:

```
Store   Day             ItemsSold
1       Monday          100
1       Tuesday         200
1       Wednesday       110
1       Thursday        10
1       Friday          1
1       Saturday        140
1       Sunday          90
2       Monday          400
2       Tuesday         150
2       Wednesday       501
2       Thursday        190
2       Friday          600
2       Saturday        180
2       Sunday          21
3       Monday          100
3       Tuesday         1050
3       Wednesday       108
3       Thursday        102
3       Friday          51
3       Saturday        40
3       Sunday          15
```

I need to be able to tell when the store will run out of items. I can get the date of the week that the process i ran, but I need to loop or somehow continue to subtract from each store and estate (Assume this is ran on Monday - store 1 will run out of Items on store 1 on Saturday, Store 2 will run out on Wednesday, store 3 will run out on Tuesday).

thank you all for your help in advance !!!

Comment: what should the output look like? is there a column other than `day` to specify ordering in table B?

Comment: Should we assume that the NumItems might be greater than one week's worth of items sold?

Comment: @hatchet7 - Yes, NumItems can be greater than 1 weeks worth of item.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

write CTE to calculate the amount of difference accumulated each day.then get the Get the largest negative on the query.

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM(
        SELECT a.Store,a.NumItems,b.Day, a.NumItems- SUM(b.ItemsSold) 
                                            OVER(PARTITION BY B.Store  
                                                    order by case when b.day='Monday'    then 1
                                                                  when b.day='Tuesday'   then 2
                                                                  when b.day='Wednesday' then 3
                                                                  when b.day='Thursday'  then 4
                                                                  when b.day='Friday'    then 5
                                                                  when b.day='Saturday'  then 6
                                                                  when b.day='Sunday'    then 7
                                                end
                                            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING  AND CURRENT ROW) diffVal
        FROM A 
        INNER JOIN B ON A.Store = B.Store
    )t
)
SELECT t.Store,t.Day 
FROM CTE t
WHERE exists (SELECT MAX(diffVal) FROM CTE WHERE diffVal < 0 GROUP BY Store HAVING t.diffVal = MAX(diffVal))
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2a472/1*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `sum` window function is supported, you can do

```
select top 1 with ties store,day
from (select a.store,b.day,
      a.numItems-sum(b.itemsSold) over(partition by b.store 
                                       order by case when b.day='Monday' then 1
                                                     when b.day='Tuesday' then 2
                                                     --/*fill remaining values*/...
                                                end
                                      ) as rem
      from tblA a
      join tblB b on a.store=b.store
     ) t 
where rem <= 0
order by row_number() over(partition by store order by rem desc)
```

The idea is to subtract the running total of itemsSold from the total items in `day` order and getting the first row where this difference is <= 0.

Comment: Would it be wise to use to mod numItems by the total for the week?

Comment: @Vamsi Prabhala results should be Store Number, Dayruns out. Example 1  Saturday

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a cumulative sum:

```
select b.*
from a join
     (select b.*,
             sum(itemsold) over (partition by store order by date) as running_itemssold
      from b
     ) b
     on a.store = b.store
where a.numitems > b.running_itemssold - itemsold and
      a.numitems <= b.running_itemsold;
```

This counts the sell out as when the number of items hits zero.  If you actually need to have an item short, you need to change the conditions so the second is `<` rather than `<=`.